# Data not showing in Kibana Discovery Tab

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, kibana, fluentd

I'm using `Kibana 7.5.2` and `Elastic search 7`.

**My First approach:** I'm sending *log data* and *system data* using fluentd and metricbeat respectively to my Kibana server. Everything working fine. I'm able to see data on the discovery page. But I had a large amount of data. so I added Kafka in between servers.

**My second approach:** Now I'm sending *log data* and *system data* to Kafka. and then from Kafka, I'm sending it to the Kibana server. For *system data* via metricbeat, I'm getting *@timestamp* field in Kibana, and for *log data* via fluent, I'm not getting *@timestamp* field.

If I'm running Kafka server individually for both one by one, everything works fine. but if I run both of them together. *System data* is not showing in the discovery tab.

Kibana index for *system data*: `metricbeat-*`

Kibana index for *log data*: `prelive-data*`

**fluentd conf**

```
<match laravel.**>
  @type kafka2

  # list of seed brokers
  brokers <my-Broker-ip>:9092
  <buffer topic>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/buffer/td
    flush_interval 3s
  </buffer>

  # topic settings

  # data type settings
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
# topic settings
  topic_key prelive-data-log
  default_topic prelive-data-log

  # producer settings
  compression_codec gzip
        # max_send_retries 1
  required_acks -1
</match>
```

**metricbeat.yml**

```
#----------------------------- KAFKA --------------------------------
output.kafka:
#  # initial brokers for reading cluster metadata
  hosts: ["<my-broker-ip>:9092"]
  topic: 'metricbeat-7.6.0-2020.03.25-000001'
```

**worker.properties** of Kafka server for system data (metricbeat)

```
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connectm.offsets
bootstrap.servers=:9092
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
rest.port=10084
rest.host.name=localhost
rest.advertised.port=10085
rest.advertised.host.name=localhost
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
plugin.path=/usr/share/java
```

**filesource.properties** of Kafka server for system data (metricbeat)

```
name=config-name
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=metricbeat-7.6.0-2020.03.25-000001
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
connection.url=http://<ES-IP>:9200
connection.username=username
connection.password=password
type.name=kafka-connect
~
```

**worker.properties** of Kafka server for system data (fluentd)

```
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connectf.offsets
bootstrap.servers=:9092
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
rest.port=10082
rest.host.name=localhost
rest.advertised.port=10083
rest.advertised.host.name=localhost
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
plugin.path=/usr/share/java
```

**filesource.properties** of kafka server for system data (fluentd)

```
name=<config-name>
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=2
topics=prelive-data-log
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
connection.url=http://<my-ES-ip>:9200
connection.username=username
connection.password=password
type.name=kafka-connect
```

I'm running my Kafka server `/usr/bin/connect-standalone worker.properties filesource.properties`

I have been stuck here for a week. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Your "file source" is actually a **sink** config. 2) Why do you need Kafka Connect if you are using FluentD and Metricbeat? 3) Please use `connect-distributed` - it is recommended for real usage

Comment: to prevent any data loss, actually it is a setup for a single server, and I'm planning to build central log. so there'll be more than 10 server, 10 kafka sever.

I'll switch to connect-distributed,  once my issue is fixed.

Comment: Fluentd and Beats don't drop data.

Comment: my elasticsearch may go down if it'll receive a very large amount of data at one go.(from more than 10 servers)

Comment: Kafka doesn't prevent that, AFAIK. Sound like a memory / sharding problem of Elasticsearch... I've had hundreds of services writing to ES at once

Comment: It's only a visualization problem or a data loss? if you query for these data from dev_tools tab they appear?

Comment: it seems that there isn't a data loss problem but you haven't update your index pattern in kibana https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html

Comment: NO, there is no data loss, when I  refresh the elasticsearch index, I can see the change in count of docs. and yes, I'm able to query the data

Comment: ok, have you already tried to update your index pattern in kibana?

Comment: have you already tried to delete all the .kibana* indices and then restart the elastic server? - make a backup of all your visualization before to do it

Comment: yeah, more than 10 times. I deleted the Elasticsearch index, then deleted the Kibana index. then restarted my service. Elasticsearch index gets auto-created, then I created the Kibana index. Nothing works!